# How can I send an Object/Array through form and hide the PHP form input from the user?

Tags: php, forms, object, post, hide

I'm trying to send an object or a array from one page to another through form. Json coding could help, but I need to send the info when the user press the form submit button. I've searched a little and tried to use serializing/coding through:

`<input type="hidden" name="geracoesc" value='. base64_encode(gzdeflate(serialize($generations))).'>`,

but the code is still shown at the HTML Code (because of the input), so, how can I hide it from an user at the moment the form is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use the $_SESSION super-global?
On your first page, start a PHP SESSION with:

```
session_start();
```

Then assign the object you want to pass to the $_SESSION like so:

```
$_SESSION['somedata'] = $object_I_want_to_hide;
```

On any following pages, you can access the data like so:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['somedata'];
```

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't realized I could use $_SESSION for this. At least by now that's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table and save that data with [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) of that user and  use from that everywhere which you need with unique session id which each visitor has.